# Why qsort from stdlib doesnt work with double values? [C]

Tags: c, double, qsort

I wrote a simple program to sort out my array. The problem is that the code works with int values only while I need my array to have `double` elements ... Any help?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

double values[] = { 88, 56, 100, 2, 25 };

int cmpfunc (const void * a, const void * b)
{
    return ( *(int*)a - *(int*)b );
}

int main()
{
    int n;

    printf("Before sorting the list is: \n");
    for( n = 0 ; n < 5; n++ )
    {
        printf("%.2f ", values[n]);
    }

    printf("\n\n");

    qsort(values, 5, sizeof(double), cmpfunc);

    printf("\nAfter sorting the list is: \n");
    for( n = 0 ; n < 5; n++ )
    {
        printf("%.2f ", values[n]);
    }

    printf("\n\n");

    return(0);
}
```

**WORKING CODE:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

double values[] = { 88, 56, 100, 2, 25 };

int compare (const void * a, const void * b)
{
    if (*(double*)a > *(double*)b) return 1;
    else if (*(double*)a < *(double*)b) return -1;
    else return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int n;

    printf("Before sorting the list is: \n");
    for( n = 0 ; n < 5; n++ )
    {
        printf("%.2f ", values[n]);
    }

    printf("\n\n");

    qsort(values, 5, sizeof(double), compare);

    printf("\nAfter sorting the list is: \n");
    for( n = 0 ; n < 5; n++ )
    {
        printf("%.2f ", values[n]);
    }

    printf("\n\n");

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: `cmpfnc` is castng to `int*`.

Comment: If you have doubles, then why are you casting to int* in your comparison function?

Comment: You cannot just say 'oh these are ints' - they are doubles. Try using sgn:

return ( sgn(*(double*)a - *(double*)b) );

Comment: @haccks why you need argument for `cmpfunc` ?

Comment: @haccks `cmpfunc` is a compare function used for [`qsort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort), and I've no idea what you're talking about

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want to sort doubles but you compare them as ints... Try this comparison function:

```
int cmpfunc (const void * a, const void * b)
{
  if (*(double*)a > *(double*)b)
    return 1;
  else if (*(double*)a < *(double*)b)
    return -1;
  else
    return 0;  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you miss `double*` conversion ?:

Also fix as one of the comment says

```
int cmpfunc (const void * a, const void * b)
{
  return (*(double*)a > *(double*)b) ? 1 : (*(double*)a < *(double*)b) ? -1:0 ;
}
```

Comment: and what about doubles that are outside the range for ints (even thought they are not here)?

Answer (score 1):

You comparison function is for `int` not for `double`:

```
int cmpfunc (const void * a, const void * b)
{
    return ( *(int*)a - *(int*)b );
}
```

<s>Note that comparing floating point is different than comparing integer values. Because of floating point precision, it's not enough to change `int *` to  `double *` above, you should use an epsilon constant for comparison.</s>

http://c-faq.com/fp/fpequal.html

**EDIT**: I striked the above paragraph as it is not relevant for sorting, see the comments section. I don't delete my answer to keep the comments visible.

Comment: Fine, did it with `eps`, doesnt work too: http://pastie.org/private/3mwz7jt3q7zicly4j3gw

Comment: Why would you need an epsilon?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth if you use only literals in your floating point array that's fine but if your array elements are the result of some computation you could be in trouble.

Comment: But this for a sort, not an equality comparison.

Comment: @ouah: No, there is no trouble that arises from using `<`, `==`, or `>` to compare floating-point numbers for `qsort`, provided NaNs are not present. These operators **have no rounding error**. When given numbers as inputs (not NaNs), `<` returns true if and only if the first operand is less than the second operand. The misguided notion that some tolerance must be used for comparing floating-point values arises from the fact that **previous** calculations may introduce errors, and this interferes with determining relationships between different numbers. But that is irrelevant to sorting.

Comment: @EricPostpischil for `qsort` I agree you actually don't care because what's important is the result of the relational operation but if you have named a comparison function, you would expect it to work fine also for the equality case.

Comment: @ouah: No, absolutely not. Using a tolerance to compare floating-point numbers, whether for equality or inequality, should **only** be in an application-specific situation. It should not be in a library routine because there is no general criterion for what constitutes equality or inequality in the face of errors. The underlying problem is not actually about equality. It is the inability to compute **any** function given incorrect inputs. This problem is exacerbated by discontinuous functions or functions with large derivates, but it exists for all functions.

Comment: @ouah: For example, if you have some `x` that would ideally be exactly a mathematical *x*, but `x` has errors because it is the result of previous computations, then it is impossible to use `x` to perfectly test whether *x* equals some *y*. But it is also impossible to use `x` to calculate arcsin(*x*), especially since the errors may have put `x` outside the domain of arcsin (e.g., greater than 1). It is even impossible to use `x` to calculate 2 • *x*. However, we can use `x` to estimate 2 • *x*, because the slope of that function is not great.

Comment: "if you have named a comparison function, you would expect it to work fine also for the equality case" - your epsilon will deeply vary depending on the situation. are you comparing the weight of two planets or two electrons (both in kilogramms)? assuming there's a generic epsilon-comparison function is just silly.

Comment: @ouah: When you use a tolerance to test whether `x` equals *y*, you are accepting some false positives in exchange for eliminating some false negatives. The decision about what false positives can be accepted depends on the application; there is no general solution suitable for library routines. And the tolerance needed to eliminate false negatives depends immensely in the prior calculations and data. Even the nature of the tolerance—relative, absolute, or something else—depends on the prior calculations and data and cannot be built into a general library routine.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I don't assume there is a generic epsilon comparison function and I don't assume we are writing a library function. I assume the epsilon here has to be specific to the OP application and values.

Comment: Anyway, all of this is irrelevant to sorting, which is why your statement does not belong in your answer. What are you going to do, sort 3.99 later than 4 because it happens to be close? Or treat them as equal so the sort chooses an order for them effectively at random? Using a tolerance in comparison when sorting does not make any sense. When sorting, just put the numbers in order.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I agree with what you are saying, but I don't understand why it contradicts what I'm saying (except for `qsort`). I'm not talking about a generic or library comparison function, I'm talking about an application specific comparison.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I'm fine this was not relevant for `qsort`.

Comment: @ouah: Sorting without a tolerance in the comparison function produces a list of numbers in order. Sorting with a tolerance generally does not. Therefore, using a tolerance is wrong.